# Regex for string following a string and forward slash

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to extract the resource group name in Azure via az cli.

The full path to a certain resource group looks like this:

`/subscriptions/b049-1234-1256-125456-125/resourceGroups/Test_ResourceGroup`

I'm trying to only extract "Test_ResourceGroup" out of the full string (which is stored in a variable), so i think the code would be something like

```
$scope = /subscriptions/b049-1234-1256-125456-125/resourceGroups/Test_ResourceGroup
$resourcegroup = $scope -match 'regex'
```

But I'm terrible at regex and not great at it. The addition challenge is that sometimes there's more strings or integers after the resource name, e.g.

```
/subscriptions/b049-1234-1256-125456-125/resourceGroups/Test_ResourceGroup/specificnameofresource/blahblah
```

But again, I just want the resource group name.

Comment: how do you decide what is the resource group name in the 2nd string?

Comment: I expect you mean what to extract the string following the literal "/resourceGroups/" up to the next forward slash or the end of the line or string. Correct? I believe Powershell supports lookaheads and (fixed-length) lookbehinds, in which you could match `(?<=\/resourceGroups\/)[^\/]+`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OT7jaK/2/). `(?<=\/resourceGroups\/)` is a *positive lookbehind*, which must be matched but is not part of the match returned. `[^\/]+` gobbles up characters other than forward slashes until it reaches a forward slash or the end of the string.

Comment: Correct, the resource group name is after /resourceGroups/

Answer (score 0):

while a pure regex solution is likely faster, this is simpler & easier to understand/modify. well, it is for me. [*grin*]

the neat thing is that the final `.Split()` will *silently* fail, so it works for "end of string" and for any position in the string.

```
$TestList = @(
    '/subscriptions/b049-1234-1256-125456-125/resourceGroups/Test_ResourceGroup/specificnameofresource/blahblah'
    '/subscriptions/b049-1234-1256-125456-125/resourceGroups/ResourceGroupZiggity'
    )

foreach ($TL_Item in $TestList)
    {
    ($TL_Item -split 'resourcegroups/')[-1].Split('/')[0]
    }
```

output ...

```
Test_ResourceGroup
ResourceGroupZiggity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex-based [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operator:

```
$resourcegroup = $scope -replace '.+/resourceGroups/([^/]+).*', '$1'
```

- `.+/resourceGroups/` captures one or more (`+`) characters (`.`), followed by `/resourceGroups/`, i.e. everything up to and including `/resourceGroups/`.
- `[^/]+` captures one or more characters that are *not* (`^`) in the character set (`[...]`) comprising `/`, i.e. everything up, but not including the next `/`, if any.
- `(...)` is a capturing subexpression a so-called *capture group*), whose captured text can be referred to in the replacement operand (substitution text) as `$1`.
- `.*` matches zero or more (`*`) remaining characters, i.e. whatever characters are left.
- Since the regex matches the entire input string, replacing what it matched with `'$1` in effect extracts just the token of interest.